# How to use "Wedding text " in Css font family?

Tags: css, stylesheet, font-family

i am going to print one student certificate . but according to customer requirement they want "wedding text". can i use wedding text for my font ? how to use it in css ?

I have downloaded one package and used it in text editor .

```
<p style="font-family:'A Dark Wedding';">Akila H Joshef </p>
```

Comment: In Css ? you can download that text (fonts) and call via css like @font-face {
    font-family: myFirstFont;
    src: url(yourfontpath.extention);
}

Comment: i tried  but not working .

Comment: @Nayana then you check the source path!!

Comment: please paste your code that what u tried, so we can help

Comment: please check i have updated my question.

Comment: remove space from your font name and also add its src (path) as my comment above and try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Step 1:**
  Convert you font to the uni format [here](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator).
- **Step 2:**
  Upload your new fonts to the folder of your web.
- **Step 3:**
  Use CSS @font-face. Manual [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/).
- **Step 4:**
  Use CSS `font-family: 'MyNewWeddingFont';`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@font-face {
     font-family: myFont;
     src: url(font_name.extenstion);
    }

div {
  font-family: myFont;
    }
```

Comment: what you mean by this url ? (src: url(wedding.woff);) ?

Comment: it is the name of font you downloaded. from where did you get the wedding font.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your font to all cross browser font formats using [**Font Squirrel**](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator)

You can convert fonts and download `@font-face` css too.

**Example `@font-face` CSS**:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```