# Fonts not applying on web

Tags: html, css

I am trying to apply custom fonts on my web-page, but some fonts are not applying. Can anyone help me please?

Here's the code:

**CSS:**

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 1-ProLook_Athletic;
   src: url('Fonts/QStrikeFonts/1-ProLook_Athletic.TTF');
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div style="font-size:35px; font-Family: 1-ProLook_Athletic"> 
  The quick brown fox
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried to use the @import instead? In the CSS

Comment: Your font-family declaration needs `'....' ` quotes . Also be sure you have the right format for the right browser

Comment: First of all, check if the font files are actually being loaded (you will need other files to be compatible in all browsers. Have a look at "@font-face file types" here http://www.miltonbayer.com/font-face/) Secondly, you need to check inside the files as the name not necessarily matches the name of the file. Try also putting the name of the font inside quotes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross browser @font-face use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519560/cross-browser-font-face-use)

Comment: Try this manual step-by-step

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28082480/how-to-use-wedding-text-in-css-font-family/28083329#28083329

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed some file formats (woff, woff2, eot, svg) and your browser seems to not support TTF files. Read this post to use webfonts:
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

---

As @Danko said, you also need to add single quotes (i.e: '') to your font name declaration.

Comment: Can't confirm that works if you don't say more about it. Maybe this specific file is corrupted? Also try to rename the file, without "-" nor "_".

Comment: Already try to rename the file these fonts are working MS Word after installing but when i try to apply on web these are not working.
also tried after rename without "-" and "_", but no result

Comment: You **need** to convert that font to the webfonts formats, otherwise it willn't works. Using fonts on web is not like activate a font on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your browser which you are currently using that supports the .TTF format file.
Add also .eot and otf format files,
Try with this:

```
@font-face {font-family: 1-ProLook_Athletic;src: url(1-ProLook_Athletic.eot);src: local('1-ProLook_Athletic'), local(1-ProLook_Athletic'), 
     url(1-ProLook_Athletic.otf) format('opentype');}
```